# Logstash/Elasticsearch Slow CSV Import

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I'm testing out the ELK stack on my desktop (ie 1 node) and thought I'd start by pulling a flat file, having logstash parse and output it to Elasticsearch. The setup was easy, but working through the flat file is painfully slow. The flat file is tab delimited, about 6 million rows and 10 fields. I've messed around with the `refresh_interval`, `flush_size`, and `workers`, but the most I've been able to get is about 300 documents per second, which means 5-6 hours. I'm having a hard time believing that that's right.

In addition to this, logstash stops reading in the file at 579,242 documents (about an hour in), but throws no errors. Any guesses as to what I'm doing wrong?

If it's relevant, my desktop is set at 10gb (with a 4gb heap size setting for ES) and 4 cores.

Comment: So it seems like something in the indexing or field mapping is slowing this down. If I pull the index field out or the mapping template out (which is mostly specifying integers, dates and non-analyzed fields), then I start getting 4-6k documents loading per second.